# Startup shortcut for other user

Tags: nsis

I'm doing a forced remote installation with PsExecute on some client machines. The problem I have is that I execute the installers as a local admin but I would like to add a startup shoortcut for a specific user. In nsis I can only choose between the users (the local admin) or All environment. How can I add a shortcut to User1's startup folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the users password you can call LogonUser + SHGetFolderPath, but I assume that you don't know the password.

Using some undocumented registry locations is the only alternative if you don't know the password and the user is not logged on:

You need parts of the [EnumUsersReg](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/EnumUsersReg) and [GetUserShellFolderFromRegistry](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/GetUserShellFolderFromRegistry) header files from the NSIS wiki and this helper macro:

```
!macro EnumUsersRegX_LoadRegFromSID SID CallbackFunc Subkey
System::Store S
ReadRegStr $R1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\${SID}" "ProfileImagePath"
ExpandEnvStrings $R1 $R1
GetFunctionAddress $0 ${CallbackFunc}
!insertmacro _EnumUsersReg_Load "$R1\NTUSER.DAT" $0 "${Subkey}"
System::Store L
!macroend
```

Then use it like this:

```
Function MyEnumUsersRegCallback
Pop $0
!insertmacro GetUserShellFolderFromRegistry "Startup" $0 $1
DetailPrint Startup=$1 ;$1 could be "" if there is some sort of error
;Call CreateShortcut here
FunctionEnd

Section
!insertmacro _EnumUsersReg_AdjustTokens
StrCpy $R1 "User1" ;username goes here
System::Call 'ADVAPI32::LookupAccountName(i0,t "$R1",i0,*i0r1,i0,*i0r2,*i)'
System::Call '*(&i$1,&t$2)i.r3'
IntOp $4 $3 + $1
${If} $3 <> 0
    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::LookupAccountName(i0,t "$R1",i $3,*ir1,i $4,*ir2,*i)i.r0'
    ${If} $0 <> 0
        System::Call 'ADVAPI32::ConvertSidToStringSid(ir3,*i.r2)i.r0' ;Win2000+
        ${If} $0 <> 0
            System::Call '*$2(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r1)'
            System::Call 'kernel32::LocalFree(i $2)'
            !insertmacro EnumUsersRegX_LoadRegFromSID "$1" MyEnumUsersRegCallback temp.key
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    System::Free $3
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

If you know the users SID, you can call the EnumUsersRegX_LoadRegFromSID macro directly without calling LookupAccountName first.

**Notes:** 
This code uses undocumented things and could therefore break in the next version of windows! You also need to be administrator and >= Win2000.

Comment: ok, it seems like a solution that is not very stable. I will see if I can do it some other way